# evaluate $\int_{0}^{1} \log\left(\frac{(\sqrt{1 - x} - 1)(\sqrt{1 - x^2} + 1)}{(\sqrt{1 - x} + 1)(\sqrt{1 - x^2} - 1)}\right) \arcsin(x^2) \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, closed-form

$$\int_{0}^{1} \log\left(\frac{(\sqrt{1 - x} - 1)(\sqrt{1 - x^2} + 1)}{(\sqrt{1 - x} + 1)(\sqrt{1 - x^2} - 1)}\right) \arcsin(x^2) \, dx = \frac{\pi^3}{12} - \pi\left(6\sqrt{2} + 2 + \log\left(\frac{3}{4} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right) - 4(2C - 7)$$

$$= \int_{0}^{1} \log\left(\frac{(1 - \sqrt{1 - x})(1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2})}{(1 + \sqrt{1 - x})(1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2})}\right) \arcsin(x^2) \, dx$$

$$=A+B$$ where

$$
A = \int_{0}^{1} \log\left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - x}}{1 + \sqrt{1 - x}}\right) \arcsin(x^2) \, dx
$$
$$
B = \int_{0}^{1} \log\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}}{1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}}\right) \arcsin(x^2) \, dx
$$

\begin{aligned}
B &\stackrel{x = \sin t}{=} -2 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} t^2 \log\left(\tan\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\right) \cos t \, dt \\
&= -16 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} t^2 \log(\tan t) \cos 2t \, dt = \ldots
\end{aligned}

Comment: where did you get this monster from?.

Comment: \begin{align}\int_{0}^{1} \log\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}}{1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}}\right) \arcsin(x^2) \, dx=0\end{align}

Comment: @pie discord server

Comment: If $C$ is supposed to be Catalan's constant, then the conjectured closed form doesn't appear to be correct. Per Mathematica, the integral is $\approx0.178134$ while your suspected value is $\approx0.208654$.